# How to convert 2d table into 3d table using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to convert 2d table into 3d table using SQL

Sample Tables:

Actual Table

```
    School  class     number 
    S1      I         23
    S1      II        12
    S1      III       54
    S2      I         57
    S2      II        12
    S2      III       81
    S3      I         12
    S3      II        25
    S3      III       65
```

And to convert it into table

```
     I       II     III
S1   23      12     54
S2   57      12     81
S3   12      25     65
```

Comment: PIVOT is how you do this. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Comment: Why pivot? LISTAGG would work fine. I am not advocating that PIVOT won't work, but LISTAGG would be more appropriate to avoid the tedious task with PIVOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sean Lange, said, use a [pivot clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE), assuming you're on 11g or higher:

```
select *
from classes
pivot (max(class_size) as class_size
  for (class) in ('I' as i, 'II' as ii, 'III' as iii))
order by school;

SCHOOL I_CLASS_SIZE II_CLASS_SIZE III_CLASS_SIZE
------ ------------ ------------- --------------
S1               23            12             54 
S2               57            12             81 
S3               12            25             65
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/948dd/1)

If you're still on an earlier version that doesn't support pivot then you can use a manual approach to do the same thing:

```
select school,
  max(case when class = 'I' then class_size end) as i,
  max(case when class = 'II' then class_size end) as ii,
  max(case when class = 'III' then class_size end) as iii
from classes
group by school
order by school;

SCHOOL          I         II        III
------ ---------- ---------- ----------
S1             23         12         54 
S2             57         12         81 
S3             12         25         65
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/948dd/8).

To show the total for each school as well, just add a `sum`:

```
select school,
  max(case when class = 'I' then class_size end) as i,
  max(case when class = 'II' then class_size end) as ii,
  max(case when class = 'III' then class_size end) as iii,
  sum(class_size) as total
from classes
group by school
order by school;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/948dd/9).

To sum the columns too, you could use `rollup()`:

```
select school,
  max(case when class = 'I' then class_size end) as i,
  max(case when class = 'II' then class_size end) as ii,
  max(case when class = 'III' then class_size end) as iii,
  sum(class_size) as total
from classes
group by rollup(school)
order by school;

SCHOOL          I         II        III      TOTAL
------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
S1             23         12         54         89 
S2             57         12         81        150 
S3             12         25         65        102 
               57         25         81        341
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/948dd/10). But it might be something you should do in your client/application. SQL*Plus can do this automatically with its `compute` command, for example.

Comment: Hi Oracle 10.5.0.41 does not support pivot

Comment: @AkshaySapra - I've added a non-pivot version; but there is no Oracle 10.5, is that your Toad version? That has nothing to do with the database version you're connecting to. You can use `select banner from v$version` to check the database server version.

Comment: thanks i din't knew that
i have checked 
its Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0

Comment: Is there any way we can add a column 'Total' to find total no of students in each school ??

Comment: @AkshaySapra - sure, just add a `sum` column; you're already grouping by school so it's simple. Added to answer.

Comment: Thanx a ton..!!
@AlexPoole
Appreciate your help 
but i am just curious 
if we have to add another row(keeping the last column 'Total' intact) in the end summing 
all the class_sizes  for a column ..

what then?

Comment: @AkshaySapra - you've wandered a long way from your original question. I've added a `rollup`, but you should really be asking a new question instead of expanding this one.